# Should I update ASUS BIOS from 0501 to 0606?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, motherboard, bios, updates

I am currently using 0501 ASUS BIOS on a P8Z68-V PRO and have noticed that whenever I boot my computer, I get 2 - sometimes 3 - ASUS logo screens during start-up. I also noticed in EZ mode BIOS, one of the CHA_FAN monitors bugs out; it flashes max 16400RPM for a second then goes back to normal ~1100RPM and keeps doing this every now and then. These aren't really critical issues; however, it is a brand new system and I wouldn't mind having everything running perfect.

I noticed there was a new BIOS available on the ASUS website and originally thought I would just flash it and see if it fixed my problems. After reading around, I am rethinking my decision as it seems I wont be able to go back to the old BIOS version if there is a problem. Also, considering my issues are minor, I am not sure I want to risk potentially bigger problems.

Has anyone had any problems with 0606? Is it likely to solve my issues?

Comment: Since a BIOS flash has the possibility of bricking your system, my policy has always been: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: Yah that's what I was thinking; but the problem is its "kinda broke" :D any other ways I might solve the issues if not a BIOS change?

Comment: It's not "kinda" broken. The fans spin at the correct rate and the ASUS boot screen is just an adornment.  It's like saying your car is broke and needs a new engine because there is a scratch on the dashboard, which an engine replacement may or may not solve the issue. A BIOS flash may or may not solve the issue. If it is brand new, I'd just send it back.

Comment: So, to answer my own question... The ASUS screen was flashing multiple times because the Marvell and JMB controllers were enabled with no connections to them. So, every time I booted, it would check for devices attached to the ports and would not find anything and then just boot normally. I disabled both in BIOS and am now getting normal boots :D

Answer (score 1):

The newest P8Z68-V PRO BIOS fixed the problems I was having with mine on earlier versions. You may find yourself unable to use certain command-prompt style utilities with a USB keyboard unless you update to the newest version... the Intel SSD firmware update tool would not respond to keyboard presses until a certain version (way above 0501) was released.

It was actually really fun because if you turned off USB Legacy support for keyboards, the BIOS wouldn't recognize the keyboard either! I managed to get it to a point where the BIOS would not recognize a keyboard or mouse so I actually had to do a clear CMOS cycle to get them working again.

As for your flashing of the ASUS logo, you might want to pay attention to how the board is behaving. If all the lights go out on the mainboard every time the screen goes blank, the board is trying to adjust your RAM settings until it finds a working combination. You may have to play with the memory settings in the BIOS to get more compatible settings for the RAM you're using.